# How to completely remove any Tomcat related data from Ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat

Previously I installed Tomcat 8, but due to some error I removed the Tomcat 8 from my system while removing Java and I also removed some files from the system manually. Then I tried to install Tomcat 8, but I was not able to install it, so I had to install Tomcat 7.

Now I want to install Tomcat 8, so is there any way to completely remove any Tomcat related information from my system and install Tomcat from fresh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a package and related files/folders, then re-adding tomcat caused some issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73830/removing-a-package-and-related-files-folders-then-re-adding-tomcat-caused-some)

Comment: that was asked 5 years ago I have a query I won't be able to get an answer for that.If you know something @George then will u tell me because i have tried purging as well.  Do u happen to know any for sure method to fix this error

Comment: Please follow the steps there and let me know how it goes.

Comment: which answer do u want me to follow

Comment: ok let begin like this, how did you remove tomcat, what command did you run?

Comment: i have not removed tomcat yet i have installed tomcat7  but previously i tried to remove using sudo apt-get remove tomcat8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65037/discussion-between-george-and-aditya1508).